# Get Average, Max, Min , Last added value and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Parameters Log` table like this:

| Log ID | Temperature | Humidity | country | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 10 | USA | 2021-09-04 10:00:51.737 |
| 2 | 20 | 20 | USA | 2021-09-04 11:09:51.737 |
| 3 | 30 | 30 | USA | 2021-09-04 12:09:51.737 |

The above table stores Temperature, Humidity likewise different parameters for the different countries at different times. I want an average of This parameter, max, min, last added value, and Last added Time for a specific day.

For example:

| Parameters | Country | Average | Min | Max | Last value | Last updated time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Temperature | USA | 30 | 20 | 40 | 30 | 2021-09-04 12:09:51.737 |
| Humidity | USA | 20 | 10 | 30 | 30 | 2021-09-04 12:09:51.737 |

This is what I did for `Temperature` :

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
        AVG(Temperature) AVG_Temp,
        MIN(Temperature) MIN_Temp,
        MAX(Temperature) Max_Temp, 
        Country  
    FROM
        Parameters_Log 
    GROUP BY
        Country 
    WHERE 
        Country = 'USA' 
        AND CAST([date] AS date) = '2021-09-04' 
)
```

First I am getting avg, Min, and Max for temperature for a country as above

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    c.Country, 
    c.AVG_Temp, 
    c.MIN_Temp,
    c.Max_Temp,
    [log].date,
    [log].Temperature 
FROM
    Parameters_Log [log] 
INNER JOIN
    cte c ON c.country = [log].country 
          AND 
WHERE
    [log].Country = 'USA' 
    AND cast([log].[date] AS date) = '2021-09-04'
ORDER BY 
    [log].[date] DESC
```

Then I am using order by date desc to get the last added Temperature value and time. Finally, I am Taking Top 1 and store in a temporary table then the same procedure following for Humidity.

Can anyone guide me on what will be the performance-wise best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot the values using `apply`. Then use `row_number()` and aggregation for the summary:

```
select country, parameter,
       avg(val), min(val), max(val),
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as last_val,
       max(date)
from (select pl.country, pl.date, v.*,
             row_number() over (partition by pl.country, v.parameter order by pl.date desc) as seqnum
      from parameters_log pl cross apply
           (values ('Temperature', pl.temperature), ('Humidity', pl.humidity)
           ) v(parameter, val)
     ) pl
group by country, parameter;
```

If you want a specific day, add a `where` clause to the subquery, such as:

```
where pl.date >= '2021-09-04' and pl.date < '2021-09-05'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2ae5179087bfe9fb9f0d6f3ba1ffd744) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @RahulBiswass . . . The issue isn't the date.  It was the missing country from the `partition by`.

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff for your suggestion. I studied the execution plan for the query suggested by you and mine. its really solve my problem.  and what I learned, in the subquery to the traversed table as per parameters and added row number to get the last Added/updated value. and in the outer query, you just did Max, min, and Avg, last values by row number =1.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. last value is picked based on max logid. apply cross join for whole result set into 2 copies.

```
-- SQL SERVER
SELECT CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'Temperature' ELSE 'Humidity' END Parameters
     , pl.country
     , CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN avg_temp ELSE avg_hum END Average
     , CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN min_temp ELSE min_hum END "Min"
     , CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN max_temp ELSE max_hum END "Max"
     , CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN pl.temparature ELSE pl.humidity END last_value
     , t.last_date "Last updated time"
FROM Parameters_Log pl
INNER JOIN (SELECT country
                 , MIN(temparature) min_temp
                 , MAX(temparature) max_temp
                 , AVG(temparature) avg_temp
                 , MIN(humidity) min_hum
                 , MAX(humidity) max_hum
                 , AVG(humidity) avg_hum
                 , MAX(logid) max_id
                 , MAX(tdate) last_date
            FROM Parameters_Log
            WHERE CAST(tdate AS date) = '2021-09-04'
            GROUP BY country) t
       ON pl.logid = t.max_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 id) c
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=48e671202de62aeff8ea737ba4d1ba5a

If desired output depends on max_date then ON condition will

```
ON pl.tdate = t.last_date
```

If desired output depends on max log_id then ON condition will

```
 ON pl.logid = t.max_id
```

Comment: [This relies on the "last value" having the highest ID](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f69c784fbd4333126a1cf0d66e042d6b). It should be the one with the latest timestamp.

Comment: I explained my downvote. Your "last_value" is the row with the highest ID. It should be the row with the newest date. [Here is a demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9df6baf20ba1128c2bbd3ad274e868c2). Note how I swapped the IDs of the inserted rows. The IDs should not matter.

Comment: I think logid is primary key. So id = 3 is inserted after 2. Questioner can explain this clearly.

Comment: I think JOINING condition plays a vital role for this. If desired result is depend on max_date then JOIN with Date otherwise join with max_id.

Comment: @Schwern please check this answer...https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab6fb8f71e69eda5ec2dd7c91731d95c

Comment: Assuming primary keys are in some sort of order is a common anti-pattern. They're not always simple incrementing integers, and data isn't always inserted in order. There's already a timestamp field for ordering the data. Your new solution now no longer depends on the ID order, [but not when there is data for other days](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=527c486c71cd0c4f107ad15b8579ccd1).

Comment: Also note there's no reason to make `varchar` fields so tiny unless there's a clear business reason. `varchar(10)` for country doesn't save any space, but it does mean you can't store "Papua New Guinea". `varchar` takes up only as much space as it needs, so use `varchar(255)` if you don't have a specific reason to restrict the size of the field.